# Problems Connecting Rays in Raycasting Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, raycasting

I'm working on a simple raycasting algorithm that I can use for 2D shadows in future games I want to make. I've got the raycasting portion figured out, but the problem is when I actually want to draw the shadows.

I know that drawing the shadows involves creating a polygon from the endpoints of each ray that was cast and subtracting its area from a "shadow mask", so that you only see what's in the area of the polygon. However, my problem is that I can't figure out how I'm supposed to sort the rays so that the polygon forms the proper shape, rather than connecting to random rays.

What I'm getting is looking something like this.

[image: Improperly connected polygon.]

So if anyone familiar with raycasting can tell me exactly how I'm supposed to connect the rays in the proper order to achieve the correct shape, I'd appreciate it. If it matters, here's my algorithm.

```
private void raycast(Point2D.Double target) {
    double theta = Math.atan2((target.y - mousePos.y), (target.x - mousePos.x));
    Point2D.Double currLoc = new Point2D.Double(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    boolean validRay = true;

    while(validRay) {
        double x = currLoc.x + Math.cos(theta);
        double y = currLoc.y + Math.sin(theta);

        // Check to see if the ray has gone out of the window.
        if((x < 0) || (x >= Game.WIDTH) || 
           (y < 0) || (y >= Game.HEIGHT)) {
            validRay = false;
        }

        // Check to see if the ray has collided with an object.
        for(Polygon c : obstacles) {
            if(c.contains(new Point2D.Double(x, y))) {
                validRay = false;
            }
        }

        if(validRay) {
            currLoc.x = x;
            currLoc.y = y;
        }
    }

    rays.add(new Point2D.Double(currLoc.x, currLoc.y));
}
```

And this is currently how I am connecting the rays into a polygon.

```
if(rays.size() > 0) { // Create the shadow mask.
    BufferedImage overlay = new BufferedImage(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D og2d = overlay.createGraphics();
    og2d.setColor(new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    og2d.clearRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);

    // Create a polygon from the endpoints of all the rays.
    Path2D.Double mask = new Path2D.Double();
    mask.moveTo(rays.get(0).x, rays.get(0).y);
    for(Point2D.Double end : rays) {
        mask.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    }
    mask.closePath();

    og2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    og2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OUT, 0.0f));
    og2d.fill(mask);

    g2d.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);
} // End creation of shadow mask.
```

Can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to "sort" the endpoints by using the angle between the endpoint and the light source itself as the criteria to sort with. Basically, the lowest angle went to the front of the list, and so on.

The only problem now is that I don't have actual endpoints on some of the vertices because the algorithm will continue past a vertex if it does not then collide with the object itself until it hits the edge of the screen, so when I connect the vertices to make the polygon, it takes "shortcuts". Here is a screenshot to demonstrate what I mean.

[image: Improperly connected polygon]